# How to sum by group and add new variable dependent by the other two variables in SAS SQL

Tags: sas

```
data work.want2;
input Y M $ ID $ volume;
datalines;
2009    JAN A1     100
2009    FEB A1     20
2009    FEB A1     80
2009    JAN A2     100
2009    JAN A2     100
2009    FEB A2     20
2009    FEB A2     80
2009    JAN A3    100
2009    FEB A3    150
2009    MAR A3    100
2011    DEC A1     100
2011    DEC A1     20
2011    DEC A2     20
2011    DEC A3     120
2011    DEC A3     80
2011    OCT A1     100
2011    OCT A2     20
2011    OCT A2     100
;
proc print data=want2;
run;

/*Code 2--> to sum by Y M ID*/
PROC SQL;
create table want3 as SELECT 
Y,
M, 
ID,
sum(volume) AS sumvolume
FROM want2
GROUP BY Y, M ,ID; 
QUIT;
/*Code 3 -->get sum by Y M*/
PROC SQL;
SELECT 
Y,
M, 
sum(sumvolume) AS sumvolume_MO
FROM want3
GROUP BY Y, M; 
QUIT;
```

I have use SAS SQL(code 2) to sum by ID, Y and M. I want to add a new variable,Monthly volume, dependent on Y and M.I have use "code 3" to get the results.

Is it possible to combine code 2 and code 3 together to get the results as following? I always get errors.

Thanks in advance.

```
  Y  M   ID sumvolume sumvolume_MO 
2009 FEB A1 100       350
2009 FEB A2 100       350
2009 FEB A3 150       350
2009 JAN A1 100       400
2009 JAN A2 200       400
2009 JAN A3 100       400
2009 MAR A3 100       100
2011 DEC A1 120       340
2011 DEC A2 20        340
2011 DEC A3 200       340
2011 OCT A1 100       220
2011 OCT A2 120       220
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Updated to reflect results wanted sum(volume) instead of raw volume.*

In general you would want to use sub queries. You could calculate the sum over the different groupings in separate subqueries and merge the results back together.

```
select a.y,a.m,a.id,a.sumvolume,b.sumvolume_mo
  from 
  (select y,m,id,sum(volume) as sumvolume
   from have
   group by 1,2,3
  ) a
  natural join
  (select y,m,sum(volume) as sumvolume_mo
   from have
   group by 1,2
  ) b
;
```

But PROC SQL in SAS will also let you include non group and non aggregate variables in the SELECT and automatically remerge the data for you. So your could get SUMVOLUME_MO by adding up the values of SUMVOLUME.

```
select y,m,id,sumvolume,sum(sumvolume) as sumvolume_mo
  from 
  (select y,m,id,sum(volume) as sumvolume
   from have
   group by 1,2,3
  )
  group by 1,2
;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I use your first code with the following to get the result.
{proc sort data=newwant2 out=newwant2 ;
   by Y M ID sumvolume_mo2 sumvolume_mo ;
data newwant3;
   set newwant2;
   by Y M ID sumvolume_mo2   ;
  if last.ID;
run;
proc print data=newwant3;
run;}

Comment: Updated to reflect that question actually wanted SUMVOLUME and not VOLUME on the final result table.

Comment: @Tom Even though `PROC SQL` permits the implicit merging of non-group and aggregate values, I think it is a code smell because it can lead to difficult to read code and bugs in more complex cases

Comment: @Snorehorse Until SAS updates PROC SQL to support more modern features like `OVER` and `PARTITION BY` being able have SAS automatically remerge statistics makes for clearer more concise code.  For this problem the explicit remerge is probably better since there are summations at two levels , but for a quick show me all records with added overall sum type query the automatic remerge is much clearer code.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to TOM's answers. I can get the results from the following codes.

```
  PROC SQL;
    create table newwant2 as
      select y,m,id, sum(volume) as sumvolume_mo2,sumvolume_mo
      from newwant
      group by Y,M,id
    ;
```

Then I use the following code to delete the duplicate rows and keep the last row of each duplicate.

```
  data newwant3;
       set newwant2;
       by Y M ID sumvolume_mo2   ;
      if last.ID;
    run;
    proc print data=newwant3;
    run;
```

Comment: The first sort can be done with an `order by` statement in the first query. And the `proc print`s aren't necessary here on S.O., unless central to your question or answer. Also an explanation of what the `by last.id` logic is accomplishing would help others in understanding your answer

Comment: I think it's still missing the `order by`in the `newwant2` query. Also it is "merging summary statistics", which can be a bad form to get used to because it can lead to hard to fix problems in more complex cases. Finally not sure why `sumvolume_mo2` is included in the `by` statement when the deepest `first\last` level being used is `last.id`?